# How to retrieve all Spring Boot I18N Messages

Tags: spring, spring-boot, internationalization

I need to retrieve all the messages I have in the file `messages_en.properties`, `messages_es.properties`, etc. depending of the current locale, but so far I can not find a way to get more than the value of a property.

What I need is nothing more than to return all the translations corresponding to the current locale, so that I can handle the internationalization with Angularjs in the front end.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why do you use Spring resources if Spring doesn't need to translate anything, but the frontend does? Why not use a format more suitable for the frontend, like JSON? angular-translate supports JSON out of the box.

Comment: What happens is that I am working on a SPA with AngularJS and this one already has many things done and all the views are rendered in the front end. I already have everything configured. My only problem is to return all messages corresponding to the messages_CURRENT_LOCALE.properties file.